# Add rich text editor to add and show rich html inside out Asp.net core MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, rich-text-editor

I am working on an Asp.net mvc core web application, and i am trying to find a way to add the ability to Add and Read rich text inside our application. so i am not sure if Asp.net MVC core provide such a capability or if there is any free third party tools to use?
Thanks

Comment: Check tiny mce https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/quick-start/, it's free to use and has pretty decent documentation.

Comment: @AdamStawarek thanks for the great reply. now i added this rich text editor and it worked well. but i have a question if i can force this rich text editor to work offline (without internet connection)? so to force the script to load locally instead of from external web site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a third party component to provide rich text editing within your application.

Tiny MCE is a well known rich text editor that is free to use.

They are trying to sell the cloud hosted version which is quite easy to add to your website.

But the free version is available as a download or as a Nuget package.

[Download or install via Nuget, NPM, or other package mangager](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/general-configuration-guide/advanced-install/)